# TableViewController - barButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableView` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I have set a `rightBarButtonItem` in storyboard. 
If I segue the normal way, everything works fine.
If I segue using from a LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics closure the barButtonItem want show, but it works.

This fails!!

```
    // Do fingerprint authentication
  if lax.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error:&error){

 let reason = "Athenticate for login"       
 lax.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason, reply: {(success: Bool, authenticationError : NSError?) -> Void in

            // check whether evaluation of fingerprint was successful
            if success {
                self.addCircle(0)
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: self)
                print("Fingerprint validated.")
```

If I rotate the device, the item become visible.
Anyone have any idea what´s going on here? or a "walk around"?
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try updating the UI using the main thread?

Comment: Could you post an image of what you see?

Comment: I tried updating, and that works. But I´m still confused why the item image are not visible, but button are active and working properly. Even stranger is, if i select a different system image like "upload" or "done", that works perfect. I´ve tried on simulator and 3 different devices????

Answer (score 0):

[Normal segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoVlw.png)

[Segue from DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iABO.png)